# Sync lists between SharePoint Online (SPO) and OnPremises 2016?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

does someone have an idea how to **sync list** data from **OnPremises** 2016 to **SharePoint Online** (O365/SPO)?

Hope someone can help.

Jesse-7777

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1:

If you want to automate this one - you need to configure by following the below article:

SharePoint Replication from Office 365 to On Premises Environments:

https://www.avepoint.com/blog/office-365/sharepoint-replication-office-365-premises-environments/

Approach 2: This can be done by coding, described below:

You can write custom PS script to handle this and this script you can configure in windows task scheduler as a job which will run automatically in interval lets say every 5 minutes and so..

For code reference and approach details you could read my below answer:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271727/how-to-create-a-list-item-to-sp-on-premise-from-sp-online/271740#271740